# Is it possible to pass multiple arguments value of a function into another function using bytes []?

Tags: c#

Need some help to write a function located inside "Application A" to pass multiple variable values using byte [] into another function located in a different application "Application B". So far, I am able to send one variable value but I am really struggling to pass multiple variable values. Thanks in advance for the help, happy holidays!

Application A code:

```
public static void eventVideoData(string appID, int ID)
        {
            string application_ID = appID;
            int idP = ID;
            string pubHeader = "/SERVICES/REQUEST/ECG/UDCMGR/";

            //Client.Publish(topic, message, MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, false);

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(application_ID);

            progrm.ADCSOAPub.Publish(pubHeader + "VIDEODATA", bytes);

            Console.WriteLine("Message Sent");

        }
```

Application B code:

```
if (e.Topic == "/SERVICES/REQUEST/ECG/UDCMGR/IMAGEDATA")
            {
                //Logic for message received?

                Console.WriteLine(msg1);

                string pubHeader = "/SERVICES/RESPONSE/ECG/UDCMGR/";

                Client.Publish(pubHeader + "IMAGEDATA", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1"));
               
                Console.WriteLine("Message Sent to Scripting Engine");
            }
```

Comment: have you thoght about using JSON...?

Comment: json might be a potential solution in other circumstances but unfortunately in this case, I have to follow some hard requirements, meaning, the solution needs to be byte array based :/

Comment: sooooooooo... pack all your data in _one_ JSON string and convert that to _one_ byte array...................?

Comment: Sorry Frank, I have never worked with Json before, could you please elaborate your answer? Maybe point me to some kind of tutorial? Thanks

Comment: in c# parameters are pushed on the stack in reverse order with the last parameter ending up on the top of the stack.  So the answer is yes provided you can bypass the syntax checking.  The calling procedure sets the stack location and then the child method pulls values off of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a tuple and send as byte array then covert back to tuple retrieve the property values, this may not be elegant but you could achieve what you wanted.

```
private byte[] ApplicationA()
        {
            (string topic, string message) obj = (
                            topic: "topic",
                            message: "message"
                        );
           
            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }

        private (string,string) ApplicationB(byte[] input)
        {
           
            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            using var ms = new MemoryStream(input);
            var  obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);
            return ((string, string))obj;
        }

        [Fact]

        public void Test()
        {
            var byteArray = ApplicationA();
            var t = ApplicationB(byteArray);
            Console.WriteLine(t.Item1);
            Console.WriteLine(t.Item2);
        }
```